# how to print on a particular printer

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I have two printers attached to the machine on which WINFORM application is installed, and I have two crystal reports RPT1 & RPT2.

So how can I send a command to printer1 to print RPT1 &
Printer2 to print RPT2.

Comment: @FreddieFabregas if I have understood, that question gives the printer dialog and then selects the appropriate printer , but in my case I dont want that, rather it should directly print to printer1 or printer2 depending on respective RPT.

Comment: Did you see the accepted answer on the link? I think you can use that, just replace the `PrintDialog` logic behind your code.

Comment: @FreddieFabregas so after
rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName just need to write the name of the printer as it shows in printer dialog box in "" , is that right ?